# How can I connect USB devices over a network

Tags: windows, networking, usb

I'm looking for a **free** solution to connect USB devices over a network on Windows.
i.e. I want to be able to connect a device to one machine and have another machine believe the device connected directly to it.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: xp and 7 (64) i guess is a must, but anything xp and higher would be ok

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After a little Google-ing I got a few decent looking results

http://www.usb-over-network.com/ - Looks the best (I.E. most stable) and has the best reviews, but costs $150

http://www.net-usb.com/ - Again comercial, but only $90

http://usbip.sourceforge.net/ - FOSS version, couldn't find out much b'cus Sourceforge is blocked on my workstation but looks OK, couldn't find many reviews/feedback on it though

Comment: 1 & 2 aren't free. 3 doesn't have a server for windows and the windows client doesn't look to stable.

Comment: @User12903 - This only means a free product is unrealistic requirement.

Comment: @user12903, if you get value out of it, shouldn't you be compensating whoever created it?

Comment: Chris, Do you really want to start discussing the motivaiton behind OS development here?

Comment: @TomO'Connor 'Open source' or something like that IDK.

Comment: I had used the Eltima solution (second in your list - net-usb.com). Really works! I like a lot that the software may share USB port over the network even to another country!